# How can i fix corrupted file system in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I shifted my docker container to new server and i think in the process my file system got corrupted.

This is the output i get

```
root@2389374b235b:/var/local/atlassian/confluence/plugins-osgi-cache# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
none           103178528 44637104  54328508  46% /
tmpfs            2023680        0   2023680   0% /dev
shm                65536        0     65536   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1      103178528 44637104  54328508  46% /BACKUPS
root@2389374b235b:/var/local/atlassian/confluence/plugins-osgi-cache# fsck /
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
fsck.ext2: Is a directory while trying to open /

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

is there any way to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to run `fsck` on a live system. Do not. Instead, you should schedule fsck to run on next reboot. That is done by adding an empty file, `/forcefsck`. Also, the error message you got is related to this instead of indicating the filesystem is corrupted.

There's two options. You can either use `shutdown -rF now` which creates the file for you and then reboots, or you can just `touch /forcefsck` and it will automatically run the fsck for you whenever you reboot the server.

Please note that this will take some time: you should have a proper maintenance window for this. Network connections will also be unavailable during the process. If this is a remote server, you should either have remote access to the console or be present.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-force-fsck-on-the-next-reboot-or-boot-sequence/